# AES encryption works only with small, 0 bytes size on the disk, files

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am interested, why encryption/decryption only works with small, 0 bytes size on the disk files, but stop working with larger files, where I get errors `The input data is not a complete block` and  `Index was outside the bounds of the array`.

I use ECDiffieHellmanCng for generating the same symmetric key on both sides.

Exchange of keys on encryption side:

```
using (ECDiffieHellmanCng sendingMode = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
{
     sendingMode.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
     sendingMode.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
     sendersPublicKey = sendingMode.PublicKey.ToByteArray(); 
     CngKey secretKey = CngKey.Import(receiversPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
     sendersKey = sendingMode.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(receiversPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)); 
     byte[] encryptedFile = null;
     byte[] ivFile = null;
     byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToSendPath);
     Encryption(sendersKey, fileBytes, out encryptedFile, out ivFile);
}
```

Exchange on receiving side:

```
using (ECDiffieHellmanCng receivingMode = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
{
     receivingMode.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
     receivingMode.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
     receiversPublicKey = receivingMode.PublicKey.ToByteArray();

     CngKey secretKey = CngKey.Import(sendersPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
     receiversKey = receivingMode.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(sendersPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
     byte[] decryptedFile = new byte[50000000];
     Decryption(encryptedFile, ivFile, out decryptedFile); 
}
```

Encrypt/decrypt methods:

```
private void Encryption(byte[] key, byte[] unencryptedMessage,out byte[] encryptedMessage, out byte[] iv)
{
     using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
     {
           aes.Key = key;
           iv = aes.IV;

           // Encrypt the message
           using (MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream())
           using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ciphertext, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
           {
               cs.Write(unencryptedMessage, 0, unencryptedMessage.Length);
               cs.Close();
               encryptedMessage = ciphertext.ToArray();
           }
      }
}

private void Decryption(byte[] encryptedMessage, byte[] iv, out byte[] decryptedMessage)
{
      using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
      {
           aes.Key = receiversKey;
           aes.IV = iv;
           // Decrypt the message
           using (MemoryStream decryptedBytes = new MemoryStream())
           {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(decryptedBytes, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                    decryptedMessage = decryptedBytes.ToArray();
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES is a block cipher requiring input to be in block size multiples, 16-bytes for AES. The simple solution is to use PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding option and the padding will be transparently added on encryption and removed on decryption.